# Select all lines of maximum 12 words that end that do not have any punctuation at the end

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-processing

I want to select all lines of maximum 12 words that end that do not have any punctuation at the end.

**Example:**

```
Love's Equal On Earth

In a moving "in" and "out of focus" image, what you see is what you want to believe about yourself.

I love the feeling.

I must confess every day for better feeling

REsTsora is a non-profit website of millions of free books, movies, software, music, websites, and more.
```

**The Output must find:**

```
Love's Equal On Earth
I must confess every day for better feeling
```

**My regex is not too good:**

```
^(.*?)(\w+\s?){1,12}(?!\S|$)
```

I want to avoid all the punctuation marks at the end of the lines, that is to find those lines of a maximum of 12 words that have nothing after the last word, no punctuation marks, nothing. My regex stops of the line, before the `'` punctuation mark.

Comment: I can write a Python code, also, but I need a regex for notepad++

Comment: Have you tried regex101? Or  regexbuddy?

Comment: I also thought of a solution that I posted, but it doesn't work. Do you think I was writing here without first testing several options?

Comment: Is `Love's` counted as one or two words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:(?:\w+\W){13}.+|.*[.!?]|)\R`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- **UNTICK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
    (?:         # non capture group
        (?:         # non capture group
            \w+         # 1 or more word characters
            \W          # non word character
        ){13}       # end group, must appear 13 times
        .+          # 1 or more any character
      |           # OR
        .*          # 0 or more any character
        [.!?]       # a punctuation, you can add all punctuation you want
      |           # OR
                    # EMPTY
    )           # end group
    \R          # any kind of linebreak
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: the problem on your regex is that it finds also blank lines...

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: Yes, it does. I thought you wanted such behaviour regarding your example. If you want to keep blank lines, just remove the last alternative in the regex use: `^(?:(?:\w+\W){13}.+|.*[.!?])\R`

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\S+ ?){1,12}(?<!\.)$
```

Flags: gm

- `^`: start of line `(\S+ ?)` => `\S+` any character that isn't
  a whitespace, repeated 1 to n times
- followed by a optional whitespace
   `?`
- All repeated 1 to 12 times `{1,12}`
- `(?<!\.)$` : $ end of line not
  preceded by a . (feel free to put more like `?,!;`)

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/0M4PqX/1).

What's interesting in this one is that you can have punctuation between your words, it will check only the last punctuation at line's end.

Comment: The OP wrote "...do not have any punctuation at the end". So, I didn't consider punctuation between words :)

Comment: You're right, I think I misunderstood the intent, I edited the message

Comment: This is the only correct solution of selecting lines here, but: a) not sure why mention other sentence ending punctuation later instead of including it within regex, b) please don't add `[edited]` type of parts, we can see something was edited.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(.*?)(\w+\s){1,12}(\w+)\s*$`
- Replace with: `(Leave EMpty)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is optimal, but try the following:

- Find what: `^(\w+[^\.,\:!\?]){1,12}$`
- Search mode: `Regular expression`

**Note:** I have only considered a few punctuation characters (`.` , `,` , `:` , `!` and `?`).

Comment: This regex wouldn't match the sentence "Hello, world" which fits the description given in the question.